# get response in codeigniter using jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Hi i have this ajax that will return total number of messages. I want that the total number of messages will automatically count from 0 to 1 without refreshing the page. How to get response in codeigniter? heres my code below

```
$this->data['getNumberOfMessages'] = $this->mm->getNumberOfMessages($this->data['id']);
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($this->data['getNumberOfMessages']);exit;
    //echo "</pre>";

    $this->data['countNumber'] = $this->data['getNumberOfMessages'];

    $response = array(
              'status'=>'ok',
              'messages'=>$this->data['countNumber']

            );
      print_r($response);
      return $this->output
                  ->set_content_type('application/json')
                  ->set_output(json_encode(array($response)));
```

my jquery ajax code

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: $(this).data("href"),
        data: {

          userId : "<?php echo $id; ?>"
        },                      
        success: function(data){
          alert(data.messages);
          $("#" + id).html("<?php echo 'You have ' ?>:" + data.messages + "messages");

        }
```

and my views

```
 <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-href="<?php echo base_url().'messages'?>" title="messages">
                    You have 
                    <?php echo $countNumber; ?>
                    message(s)</a>
```

can someone help me figured this thing out? I want that it will automatically count without refreshing my page.
any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, hello! what is the problem?

Comment: my problem is i want that when i received messages it will display to my page you have 1 messages but the 1 will automatically display without refreshing the page first

Comment: why is that when i alert this one alert(data.messages); it is undefined